# Получить время отправленного сообщения в Телеграм бот на Python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу бота на Python. В чем задача: мне нужно получить время отправленного сообщения. Пользователь бота вводит сообщение и отправляет его и мне нужно получить время, когда пользователь его написал и внести это время в базу данных(mySQL). Как это реализовать?  Использую PyTelegramBotApi.

Comment: Ребят, делаю бота с таким же принципом. Нужно получить время , когда пользователь отправи сообщение. Только на PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего вопрос не актуален, но правильного ответа так и не дали, поэтому лучше поздно чем никогда)
Вообще не пользовался ботом телеграмма, но нашел инфу за 2 минуты

```
import telebot, time

tconv = lambda x: time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d.%m.%Y", time.localtime(x)) #Конвертация даты в читабельный вид

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    ...
    print(tconv(message.date)) # Вывод даты типо 20:58:30 05.07.2020
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime
mess_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

И записать переменную mess_time в БД

Comment: Извините, но в вопросе не спрашивается о том как поучить текущее время.

Comment: @0xdb получить текущее время во момент принятия сообщения - и будет "время, когда пользователь его написал", разве нет?

Answer (score -1):

```
# Получим время пользователя из сообщения
d = query.json['message']['date']
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(d)
```